# OVH Apiv6: using test mode (dryrun)

Tags: php, ovh

I am trying to migrate ovh api from **SoAPI** to **APIv6**, but i cannot use testMode (**$dryrun**) to not debit my account.

any idea on how to do in the new API.

Thank you.